# What is the first movie where the audience believes a dream sequence is reality until the character wakes up?

Tags: first-appearance

In Spy Kids (2001), Gregorio Cortez almost think that he smash the big guy into windows at school & all kids claps for it. even audience view the scene what he think.

But in reality, he actually didn't smash the big guy.

so What is the first movie to show thinking way in such like this?

Comment: This is going to be a tough question to answer. From brief research, one of the first films with a dream sequence was Buster Keaton's Sherlock Jr. However, that sequence was a true dream, and the audience sees Keaton's character fall asleep before the dream sequence. I don't know how you would find the first dream sequence where the audience becomes aware that the dream is a dream at the same time as the character dreaming.

Comment: [Related](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42795/what-is-the-earliest-movie-in-which-it-all-turns-out-to-have-been-a-dream/42809#42809) (and possibly even a duplicate)

Comment: Long before Spy Kids that's for sure.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate of that question, as that addresses the majority (or entirety) of the plot as opposed to a small vignette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fantasia (1940)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantasia_(1940_film)) by Disney where Mickey Mouse has a dream that he is a wizard, but is actually dreaming. The audience doesn't know he's dreaming until he wakes up to find the room is flooding because his dream was driving the brooms to poor water in the real-world.

Comment: great example! I would say this is a dream vs a daydream but the OP may agree with you

Comment: I have reached my daily vote limit, will have to get your +1 tomorrow

Comment: @m1gp0z OP hasn't logged in since they asked the question over 2 1/2 years ago, so we're unlikely to ever find out.

Comment: @F1Krazy just an opportunity to earn badges on old questions :)

Comment: @F1Krazy, I just saw that a minute ago, you are right

Comment: I don't think Fantasia is the first, but I can't think of a specific example right now. I just have the feeling that there were 30's noir movies that did this.

Answer (score 1):

This specific trope is called a [Daydream Surprise](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DaydreamSurprise)

> Creators sometimes like to tweak the audience, and what better way than fudging the reality of the work itself? Or maybe they want to give the fans a little taste of something long awaited, but without actually committing it to canon. Enter the Daydream Surprise. The work's perspective subtly shifts inside a character's head, and while viewers think they're seeing the story play out, they're really just seeing that character fantasize. Usually, a nearby character will then snap the dreamer back to reality, and the viewers suddenly find out that the last 20 seconds were a lie!

The earliest example I could see from the page is from a 1962 episode of the Twilight Zone

> Possibly best known from the The Twilight Zone episode "An Occurrence at Owl Creek Bridge" (adapted from the short story of the same name by Ambrose Bierce), in which a Civil War prisoner being hanged from the eponymous bridge manages a miraculous escape, makes his way across miles of hostile countryside to his home, stumbles inside to the welcoming arms of his loving wife... and finishes his drop on the end of the rope and dies.

Comment: The [related and possibly duplicate](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42795/what-is-the-earliest-movie-in-which-it-all-turns-out-to-have-been-a-dream/42809#42809) answer here suggests that this is a lot older.

Comment: I read the other question but it seems to deal with actual dreams (while sleeping) as opposed to the daydream sequence given as an example

Comment: The question references "dream sequences" multiple times.

Comment: Splitting hairs here, "dream sequence" is used **once** in the title, Spy Kids is used as an example of the Daydream Surprise Trope